# java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY013050: RESTeasy Provider Factory is null, do you have the ResteasyBootstrap listener configured?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, resteasy

After upgrading from EAP7 to Wildfly14, receiving below error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY013050: RESTeasy Provider Factory is null, do you have the ResteasyBootstrap listener configured?

Answer (score 0):

***During upgrade from EAP7 to Wildfly14***

Inside application ear package was also resteasy-spring jar of previous Jboss version was packaged.

after replacing resteasy-spring library with the target version of Jboss/Wildfly, error was gone.

Hope it helps in some cases.

***Of course not the solution for every RESTEASY013050***